# Vapor 3 on Heroku: REPL?

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor

Is there a way to get access to a REPL on Heroku in Vapor 3? If so, how?

I've tried `heroku run swift run --repl`, but Heroku replies: `bash: swift: command not found`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's unfortunately not possible. The Swift toolchain is not part of the application image (slug), because it would overshoot the size limit, and does not add anything useful when running the application itself.

If you want to experiment with Swift on Linux without installing Linux yourself, I'd suggest installing Docker. Once you have it set up, the following command will give you a REPL:

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged swift:latest swift
```